# MariaDB service won't start on FreeBSD jail

Tags: mysql, freebsd, mariadb, jail, bsd

Just set up a dedicated database jail running databases/mariadb55-server and for some reason it won't start on demand nor on boot.

Any suggestions?

```
# service mysql-server start
Starting mysql.
/usr/sbin/daemon: Permission denied
/usr/local/etc/rc.d/mysql-server: WARNING: failed to start mysql
```

Not sure what permissions this error is referring to.

*My environment*:

```
# env
USER=root
LOGNAME=root
HOME=/root
SHELL=/bin/csh
BLOCKSIZE=K
MAIL=/var/mail/root
MM_CHARSET=UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/root/bin
TERM=screen-256color
HOSTTYPE=FreeBSD
VENDOR=amd
OSTYPE=FreeBSD
MACHTYPE=x86_64
SHLVL=1
PWD=/var/db
GROUP=wheel
HOST=db
```

Another question is, why mariadb55-server doesn't respect the /usr/local/etc/my.cnf rather uses /var/db/mysql/something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK i resolved the issue. Culprit was setting my **/etc/pw.conf** umask from **022** to **007** (*trying to make it a bit more secure*) which resulted in creating basejail's **/usr** directory with **750** permissions instead of **755** so offending **/usr/sbin/daemon** couldn't get reached from jail.

Immediately after rebooting the jail service started and works as it supposed to.

I kinda deserve a slap for this mess and I'm sorry. Lesson learned :/